# Display icons in Neo4j web browser

Tags: neo4j

I would like to display icons within nodes of Neo4j web browser by using this repo: https://github.com/graphadvantage/neo4j-browser-icons/ but I can't make it work.

Could you help with the installation? (I'm using docker image of Neo4j 3.5)

Comment: I can help you with the installation.

Comment: Hi @Raj, could you describe shortly with an answer? I guess many people would be interested in that. I can't figure out how to use file streamline-icons.png and I got execution error in streamline.cypher at line 100.

Comment: Sure, added the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use post_connect_cmd to set the style from the grass file that is available in the above GitHub repo.

No need to run the Cyphers, using the existing grass file will work.

For using above grass file you need to modify the `neo4j.conf` to whitelist the domain or allow CORS and add the post_connect_cmd to set the style:

**Add the following lines at the end of the neo4j.conf file and restart the Neo4j.**

```
#********************************************************************
# Custom Styling for Neo4j Browser
#********************************************************************
browser.remote_content_hostname_whitelist=github.com,githubusercontent.com
browser.post_connect_cmd=style https://raw.githubusercontent.com/graphadvantage/neo4j-browser-icons/master/graphstyle.grass
```

**This works for me. You can verify by creating a node:**

```
CREATE(n:Upload{name:'Upload'}) return n
```

Comment: Thanks. So actually, it just consists in using attribute icon-code in grass file. Even drag and drop of a grass file in the Web browser works.

Comment: Yes, drag n drop also works. But I personally think this is better, As drag and drop applied only for that browser. If you open the Neo4j browser on a different system then you may need to drag and drop again. In case you are sharing this Neo4j with others, you may need to share the grass file with them.